# I want to interrupt a specific process when a specific object hits it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to interrupt the process when it responds to a specific object.

I wanted to interrupt `SinkDeath()` by sorting through the tags of the object and changing the value of the bool to true, but it doesn't work!

script1

```
    public async void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Weapon/Arrow"))
        {
            IsArrow=true;
        }
        _slimesReceiveSe.ReceiveSe();
    }
```

script2

```
public async void SinkDeath()
{
    if (GetComponent<Script1>().IsArrow==true)
    {
        return;
    }
    await UniTask.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15f));
    this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

I want to change it to `IsArrow=true` in script1 and interrupt the ``SinkDeath()``` method in script2 when it hits a specific object.

I didn't get any response on this part.

```
    if (GetComponent<ChildrenSlimeWeaponCollider>().IsArrow==true)
    {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain you problem clearly, i am not sure that anybody understands what you just write above .

Comment: can you please tell me then when you want it to be false, or you want it to be true always after the collision happens ?
I am preparing the answer.
@eichan114

Comment: @QusaiAzzam
We want it to be false at the start of the game. Then a collision occurs and `if (GetComponent<ChildrenSlimeWeaponCollider>().IsArrow==true)
    {
        return;
    IsArrow==true) { return; }`I want to set it back to false after this process is over.

Comment: When Are you excusing `SinkDeath()` function, are you excuting it in a loop ?

Comment: when do you want to execute `SinkDeath ` ?

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We succeeded in suspending the `SinkDeath()` function by using the `cancellationToken` in UniTask.

script1

```
public async void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Weapon/Arrow"))
    {
             await GetComponent<ChildSinkDeath>().CancelToken();
             return;        
    }
    _slimesReceiveSe.ReceiveSe();
}
```

script2

```
public class ChildSinkDeath : MonoBehaviour
{
private CancellationTokenSource hoge = null;


public async Task CancelToken()
{
    hoge.Cancel();
    GetComponent<ChildAnimationHandler>().ChildFloat();
}

public async UniTask SinkDeath()
{
    hoge = new CancellationTokenSource();

    await UniTask.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15f), cancellationToken: hoge.Token);

    this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add the following to your Script1.cs :

```
public delegate void OnArrowCollision();
public static event OnArrowCollision onArrowCollision;

public void RaiseOnArrowCollision()
{
  if (onArrowCollision != null)
    {
         onArrowCollision.Invoke();
    }
        
}

  public async void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
  {
     if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Weapon/Arrow"))
      {
          IsArrow = true;
          RaiseOnArrowCollision();
      }

      _slimesReceiveSe.ReceiveSe();
   }
```

in the second Script "Script2.cs" you can listen to the new event of collision and execute whatever function you like :

```
        private void OnEnable()
        {
            Script1.onArrowCollision += Script1_onArrowCollision;
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            Script1.onArrowCollision -= Script1_onArrowCollision;
        }

        private void Script1_onArrowCollision()
        {
           _ = SinkDeath();
        }


        public async UniTask SinkDeath()
        {
            await UniTask.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15f));
            GetComponent<Script1>().IsArrow = false;
            await UniTask.Yield();
        }
```

So the execution will be like this : 
1 - Collision happens.
2 - Raise Collision Event.
3 - Execute SkinDeath Function.
4 - IsArrow becomes true.
5 - Wait for 15 seconds.
6 - IsArrow becomes false.

Comment: @eichan114 check the execution above and let me know.